# Twig and Custom Autoloaders

Tags: php, twig, autoloader

I use a custom autoloader to load the classes for my web app, but I have just started working on integrating Twig.  Twig, however, wants to register its own autoloader, and this is breaking my autoload function.  How do I register multiple autoloaders that can run side-by-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.  Twig registers its autoloader using the spl_autoload_register function.  I was defining mine with a function named __autoload, not manually registering it.  Both were being registered, but for some reason, my function wasn't getting triggered.  I tried manually registering my function via spl_autoload_register, and both autoloaders work fine.